# Could not find gem 'rails' at main folder error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Trying to setup an Rails project. After running `gem install rails` it returned an error related to MSYS2 (looks like it wasn't installed), the rails gem is apparently correctly, but running `rails -v` or other commands related to it like `rails -s` inside the created project folder, it returns the following message

```
Could not find gem 'rails (~> 7.0.3, >= 7.0.3.1)' in locally installed gems.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Running `bundle install` also bring some error messages like

[https://prnt.sc/P3k9rqFiYFVT]

[https://prnt.sc/ESd1s_jSKzOj]

I already installed MSYS2 manually because `ridk install` command didn't work and think the main error is related to it, if there's a way to find the root of problem I would be pleased.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an issue with Rails or the Rails gem. You've got problems installing the other gems that your app relies on, so your bundle isn't complete. Once you've sorted those, Rails should run ok.

Comment: You mean install these mannually with "Once you've sorted those, Rails should run ok"?

Comment: I kind of mean you're asking the wrong question. You can't run Rails because your bundle isn't complete. Your bundle isn't complete because of the other errors you've posted links to. You should ask – in separate questions – how to fix those errors

Comment: now it's clear for me, ty